# Testing Linq to Entities Queries

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-entities

What is the best way to do this?  Typically when I create a Query in SQL I create it in the designer of visual studio and I run it multiple times to see my results....

Is there such a thing for Linq-to-Entities?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

Comment: LinqPad offers some very basic examples as well to get you started on many of the concepts related to LINQ. I find it very useful to run the queries using LinqPad before integrating them into the solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Entity Profiler](http://efprof.com/) has been a great product we have used to profile our Entity Framework generate SQL queries.